# Updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 12.0.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebaseui

I have upgraded my Android Studio recently first I got an Error with AAPT2. This one is nor occuring anymore. Therfor I have a new one.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 12.0.0.

but I have used version 12.0.0 already.

**build.gradle (app):**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:12.0.0'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:12.0.1'
```

Both Firebase and the google play services should have the same version.